# Apply a font change script in master pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

[InDesign script to replace all fonts in a document](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116203/indesign-script-to-replace-all-fonts-in-a-document)

I used the above script to change fonts in multiple documents, only to find out that it doesn't also change the fonts in the Master Pages, which I need it to do. Is there a way to edit the script or create a new one that will also change the fonts in the master pages and not just the main document?

Answer (score 1):

I took the script provided in your linked thread and researched a bit and found the way to do it through script.

See the original script with my addition below:

```
// Replace fonts in current INDD doc according to a set list
// Each line in theFontReplacements: 'Existing Font', 'Existing Style', 'New Font', 'New Style',
// Styles are optional - leave blank ('') if unwanted

var mydoc = app.activeDocument;

var theFontReplacements = [
  'Minion Pro','Regular','Calibri','Regular',
  'Trade Gothic LT Std','Regular','Calibri','Regular',
  'Trade Gothic LT Std','Bold No. 2','Calibri','Bold',
  'Trade Gothic LT Std','Oblique','Calibri','Italic',
];

for (i = 0; i < (theFontReplacements.length/4); i++) {

  //*****
  app.findChangeTextOptions.includeMasterPages = true; //change master pages too (reference http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_FindChangeTextOption.html)
  //*****
  app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.findTextPreferences.appliedFont = theFontReplacements[i*4];
  if (theFontReplacements[(i*4)+1] != ''){
    app.findTextPreferences.fontStyle = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+1];
  };
  app.changeTextPreferences.appliedFont  = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+2];
  if (theFontReplacements[(i*4)+3] != ''){
    app.changeTextPreferences.fontStyle  = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+3];
  };
  mydoc.changeText();

};
```

Just add the line I "highlighted" (app.findChangeTextOptions.includeMasterPages = true;) to the script and you are good to go.

You can check the reference I added for other options you can use, like change hidden or locked layers.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You must check the **Include Master Pages** icon at the Find/Change window to allow changes in master pages

[image]